# How to keep sheets from tangling and staying wet in the dryer

Tags: home, clothing, laundry

Sheets in the dryer sometimes get tangled up among themselves, which keeps them from drying evenly because the hot air doesn't reach the moisture inside the twists. Sometimes they also wrap around something smaller (like a pillowcase, towel, shorts) and don't let it move freely, so when I pull out the laundry, I have a mostly-dry sheet with a wet ball of something wrapped up like Hershey's Kisses.

How can I keep the different pieces of laundry from getting tangled up in the dryer so they can all get dry?

Comment: Hang them on a clothesline :-)

Comment: @jamesqf With three dogs in the yard, not a good idea. :-)

Comment: Well, I have two in my yard, and it has never been a problem.

Comment: Hang them higher :)

Answer (score 2):

We have a policy in our house to dry the sheets separately from everything else. In other words, we run a separate load for small items like the pillow cases, shirts, socks etc. We also open up the flat and fitted sheets before we put them in the dryer, rather than putting them in as a ball. We haven't had a "Hershey's Kiss" situation since we started doing this.

Comment: And for drying quilted items, toss in a few tennis balls to break up clumps of filling and to fluff the quilt electrostatically.

Comment: Just to add on, I usually try to run 3x20 minutes or 2x30 instead of 60 minutes (for example) so I can unravel the sheets midway through the drying cycle. Just make sure you're quick if you do this so too much heat doesn't escape.

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase laundry bags specifically made to separate clothing articles. some names of these bags are called Hosiery/Laundry Bags, or Washer/Dryer laundry bags.